# Strange request URLs when running ASP.Net Core Application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple MVC ASP.Net application with a health check. The check is routed using an attribute: `[HttpGet("health")]`

When running it locally, I browse `http://localhost:7000/health` and get a successful result back. The logs look like this:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
  [00:00:34.796]: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:7000/health  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: [00:00:34.796]: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:7000/health  
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter[1]
  Request successfully matched the route with name '(null)' and template 'health'.
```

However, once I deploy to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, none of my normal request work. If I browse `http://(myAppName).us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/` these are the logs I get:

```
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
  [23:56:39.079]: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://172.31.27.29//(myAppName).us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/health  
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware[1]
  Request did not match any routes.
```

Note how for some reason the request URL gets an IP address stuck in there. No idea where its coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a misconfiguration in AWS. I had set the health check URL with an absolute address, which failed. Then when I tried to health check manually, the load balancer didn't let me through because the AWS health check was failing.

I thought the logs were from my manual check, so I assumed that amazon was adding weird things to my request. But really it was just a misconfigured health check in AWS.